# share config.js for all web page (require.js)?

Tags: requirejs, config

I have following lines which are included in every single html page.

```
<script>                                                                                                                                                      
  var require = {                                                                                                                                                      
  baseUrl: '{{ STATIC_URL }}'                                                                                                                                        
  };                                                                                                                                                             
</script>
{% load js %} <!-- django.js + require.js -->
{% django_js_init %}
<script data-main="{% static 'site_common/js/config.js' %}"  src='{% static "site_common/bower_components/requirejs/require.js" %}'></script>
```

Now, in one of html page, I do 
require('foo'), and the chrome shows requirejs failed to load 'foo'

I need to do nested require as in

```
require(['site_common/js/config.js']),
  function() {
    require(['foo']),
      function(Foo) {
      }
    });
  });
```

What's the point of `<script data-main="{% static 'site_common/js/config.js' %}"  src='{% static "site_common/bower_components/requirejs/require.js" %}'></script>` ?

https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/354 says the above line should do the job of importing 'config.js' for all the page?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at example-multipage-shim (https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage-shim) and see if it is suitable for your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've looked at the example, and it uses the nested require...